# Scala Slick. Transactionally insert batch

Tags: scala, transactions, slick

I am already have `create` method for single entity:

```
override def createEntity(entity: Entity) =
  db.run(
    ( for {
      existing <- Entity.filter(e => e.id === entity.id).result  //Check, if entity exists
      e <- if (existing.isEmpty)
             (Entity returning Entity) += Entity(entity.id, entity.name)
           else {
             throw new DuplicateException(s"Create failed: entity already exists")
          }
        } yield e ).transactionally
      )
```

How can I reuse this method for transactionally creating list of entities?

```
//Doesn't work
override def createEntities(entities : List[model.Entity]) = {
    db.run(
      ( for {
          e <- entities
        }
        yield createEntity(e)
      ).transactionally
    )
}
```

I am newbie in `slick` :(

**P.S.** Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you're trying execute multiple *inner* `db.run`s (declared in your `createEntity`) from code called from within *outer* `db.run` (declared in `createEntities`). These *outer* and *inner* `db.run`s are conceptually unrelated and thus are not executed within same transaction.

**A bit of perspective**

To better understand what is going on and how to deal with situation like this we'll have to talk about monads, specifically `DBIOAction` (I will try to explain conceptually what is going on with great deal of simplification and cutting some corners since rigorous explanation will take too much time and not that relevant for the solution).

One way of thinking about `DBIOAction` is as a canned list of steps (code) explaining how to execute queries and get results from db. `db.run` does actual execution of this list.

Important thing to note is that this list contains steps (code) to be executed in the database (SQL queries) as well as in your local jvm (runtime scala function objects).

Furthermore every element of this list (piece of code) depends on previous either by taking input from previous or by being generated by previous. This all is glued together by series of `map`/`flatMaps` (`for` expressions get desugared to it). This looks something like this:

```
(1) sql code (generates input for (2))
(2) jvm code (gets input from (1), and generates (3))
(3) sql code (generates input for (4))
(4) jvm code (gets input from (3), and generates (5))
...
```

Note that plain jvm code gets woven into this list and can be anything as long as it generates instructions for the next step (or delivers end result in case of code passed to `map`).

This gives monads in general (and thus `DBIOAction`) huge expressive power since this enables dynamic behavior of the whole list (i.e. every "jvm code" step can influence computations down the road).

The side effect of the fact that you can do anything in "jvm code" step is that you also can spawn and execute new unrelated lists of computations (this is what you are trying to do) which may be fine but also confusing if you are not thinking in terms of monadic composition.

**So, what it is that you can actually do to solve the problem?**

If you're concerned with code reuse I'd recommend you to get rid of *inner* `db.run`s and extract `DBIOAction` that you can later `db.run` in `createEntity` and (with some tweaks) in `createEntities`.

You should be able to rewrite your code to something similar to this (I do not have your exact version of entities so treat this as a pseudocode):

```
  def createQuery(entity: Entity) = ( for {
    existing <- Entity.filter(e => e.id === entity.id).result
    e <- if (existing.isEmpty)
      (Entity returning Entity) += Entity(entity.id, entity.name)
    else {
      throw new DuplicateException(s"Create failed: entity already exists")
    }
  } yield e )


  def createEntity(entity: Entity) = db.run(createQuery(entity))

  def createEntities(entities : List[model.Entity]) = {
    db.run(DBIO.sequence(entities.map(createQuery(_))).transactionally)
  }
```

Note the application of `DBIO.sequence` combinator to list of `DBIOAction`s and applying `transactionally` to the result before actual `db.run`.

**Sidenote**

If you have control over your schema I'd recommend you to move enforcing "unique id" constraint from entity creation in code to your database.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like that:
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0/dbio.html#sequential-execution

I did not test the code, and I am not used to slick 3.x, but I think it should be something like this:

```
override def createEntities(entities : List[model.Entity]) = {
  db.run(DBIO.seq(entities.map(createEntity):_*).transactionally)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile :(